# The panel where the packages are listed and the panel with my data sets are invisible

Tags: user-interface, rstudio

[image]

I could not understand where I clicked, but suddenly the part on the bottom right with my data sets and packages disappeared. What can I do?

Comment: From your options menu: "View" -> "Panes" -> "Show all panes"

Answer (score 1):

You may have accidentally collapsed the frames to the right.  If you mouse-over the right border, then click and drag-left, you will probably be able to see them again.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was solved when I click on the below

[image]